# Link icon and social networks

Tags: ios, integration, social-networking

How would I connect a icon to login for a social network (i.e. Facebook) and once logged in the icon will link to the profile picture in Xcode?

Comment: I'm not completely clear on "once logged in the icon will link to the profile picture in Xcode?". Can you please elaborate on your problem.

Comment: Xcode is irrelevant in this. It is an IDE.

Comment: basically there needs to be an icon, for example a fb icon on the main page of the app. once its clicked to login and then i need it to link to the profile picture and it will appear on the main page of the app

Answer (score 1):

Use the facebook API to login first. I am sure they all provide their logos to place into the app. Once you are logged in, try looking through API. If not, you can use a javascript command inside a `UIWebView` from logon information to link the `UIIimage` to the profile picture.